# Filter on columns using read_parquet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parquet

I would need to filter a date column based on two other dates in a dataframe (dataframe is too big and cannot load it and do it as usual in pandas), I used the following snippet of code but I am not able to do it as it throws error:

```
filename = "df.parquet"
date_filters = [('current', '>=', 'start'), ('current', '<=', 'end')]

df = pd.read_parquet(filename, engine='pyarrow',filters=date_filters)
```

This is the error that I get.

```
ArrowNotImplementedError: Function greater_equal has no kernel matching input types (array[timestamp[us]], scalar[string])
```

I am wondering if there is another way of doing it as the dataframe that I am trying to load is extremely large.